# A question about will_paginate's with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, ruby-1.9, will-paginate

As my title, I want set multiple conditions in will_paginate, that's my model's code

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :province
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :region
  belongs_to :street
  belongs_to :estate
  def self.search(city_id, region_id, layout, page)
    conditions = []
    conditions.push("city_id = #{city_id}")
    conditions.push("region_id = #{region_id}")
    conditions.push("layout = #{layout}") if layout!=0
    paginate :per_page => 5, :page => page,
      :conditions => conditions
  end
end
```

invode it in controller:

> @rooms = Room.search(city,
>   region, layout, params[:page])

but..doesn't work right..It just consider the first condition.

who can give me a sample code??  Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :province
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :region
  belongs_to :street
  belongs_to :estate
  def self.search(city_id, region_id, layout, page)
    conditions = []
    conditions.push("city_id = #{city_id}")
    conditions.push("region_id = #{region_id}")
    conditions.push("layout = #{layout}") if layout!=0
    paginate :per_page => 5, :page => page,
      :conditions => conditions.join(' and ')
  end
end
```

This would concatenate all of your conditions with "AND".

The reason your code doesn't work is that when you use an Array for condition, the first element should be a condition with SQL params and remaining elements - are param values. For example:

```
Room.paginate(:conditions => ['city_id = ? and region_id = ?', city_id, region_id])
```

That's why it only considers the first condition.

Comment: Absolutely, I don't tweet much though. Maybe I should...: http://twitter.com/#!/aspushkinus

Answer (score 3):

A better approach would be to use conditions like this(which is preferred in Rails)

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :province
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :region
  belongs_to :street
  belongs_to :estate
  def self.search(city_id, region_id, layout, page)
    conditions = {}
    conditions.merge!(:city_id => city_id)
    conditions.merge!(:region_id => region_id)
    conditions.merge!(:layout => layout) if layout!=0
    paginate :per_page => 5, :page => page,
      :conditions => conditions
  end
end
```

This will eliminate the risk of SQL injection.